# How can I efficiently search for 5000 ngrams in a list of 100B sentences in pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark

I have a dataframe of ~5000 ngrams which look like this

| ngram |
| --- |
| abc |
| abcd |
| abcd auto |

My database has around 100B records which look like this:

| sentences | category | person | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| my abc has cow | domestic | adam | progress |
| abcda knows teaching | occupation | mary | not started |
| xyz company | business | xavier | finished |

I want to find matches of the ngrams in the 100B for getting some high level stats (total matches, with some category/no category, different people assigned, status etc.)

I did multiple things:

1. Inverted index
   After basic normalization (remove numbers, special chars etc.), the 100B sentences were converted to unigrams, bigrams, trigrams and 4 grams. Inverted indices were created from each entity. The issue is the time taken in creating the inverted index.
2. Bypass inv index and generate stats.
   I didn't create the index as such, without that created ngrams and generated stats using groupby.
3. This, I didn't try on the large set, however tried on a real small set.

```
  def get_matches(ngram,df):
      matching_df=df[df['sentence'].str.contains(ngram)] # dataframe where desc has the kw
      #find reqd stats from matching_df
      stats=generate_stats(matching_df)
      return stats
```

I tried this function on a pandas dataframe (10M rows), however it is not scalable. What is the best way to do this task ?